# TAB-indentation within VB6 IDE?

Tags: vb6, ide, indentation

Related: [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/57)

As I work with some legacy VB6, I wonder, is there a solution to use TAB-indentation within VB6 IDE? I tried to find something for tab-indentation, and I could find only the following within the VB6 IDE,

[image: screenshot from Microsoft]

The "Tab Width" allows one to define how many spaces to put for indentation. I guess one solution is to use one-space per tab for the future. But is there any way to use TAB-indentation within VB6 IDE instead of spaces? Perhaps an IDE add-on or a dirty hack?

Comment: I dont think so, even if you manually indent with a tab the IDE will replace that tab with spaces automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this two plugins:

mz-tools:
https://www.mztools.com/v8/onlinehelp/MZTools8Help.html

VBTools AddIn - Auto indent
http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=58305&d=1184763794